# Week Range Output in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working on an R script that would display the weekday range and week the dates fall in, in a data frame.

output i'm trying to display

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------
>  DateRange                    | Week                            
> --------------------------------------------------
>  1/7/2018  - 1/13/2018        |   2
> --------------------------------------------------
>  1/14/2018  - 1/20/2018       |   3
> --------------------------------------------------
>  1/21/2018  - 1/26/2018       |   4
> --------------------------------------------------
> ```

```
library(data.table)
dd <- seq(as.IDate("2018-01-01"), as.IDate("2018-04-10"), 1)
dt <- data.table(i = 1:length(dd),
                 day = dd,
                 weekday = weekdays(dd),
                 day_rounded = round(dd, "weeks"))
## Now let's add the weekdays for the "rounded" date
dt[ , weekday_rounded := weekdays(day_rounded)]
## This seems to make internal sense with the "week" calculation
dt[ , weeknumber := week(day)]
dt$weekday_rounded <- NULL
dt$day_rounded <- NULL
dt
```

Comment: What is your undesired result? Code and text do not mention problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, then `lubridate` can help:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dd <- seq(as.IDate("2018-01-01"), as.IDate("2018-04-10"), 1)
dt <- data.table(i = 1:length(dd), day = dd)

dt[, week       := week(day),]
dt[, week_start := floor_date(day, unit = "week"),]
dt[, week_range := interval(week_start, week_start + days(6))]
dt[, week_start := NULL,]
```

**Output:**

```
       i        day week                     week_range
  1:   1 2018-01-01    1 2017-12-31 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
  2:   2 2018-01-02    1 2017-12-31 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
  3:   3 2018-01-03    1 2017-12-31 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
  4:   4 2018-01-04    1 2017-12-31 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
  5:   5 2018-01-05    1 2017-12-31 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
  6:   6 2018-01-06    1 2017-12-31 UTC--2018-01-06 UTC
  7:   7 2018-01-07    1 2018-01-07 UTC--2018-01-13 UTC
  8:   8 2018-01-08    2 2018-01-07 UTC--2018-01-13 UTC
  9:   9 2018-01-09    2 2018-01-07 UTC--2018-01-13 UTC
 10:  10 2018-01-10    2 2018-01-07 UTC--2018-01-13 UTC
 .......
```

Comment: Those two packages have a lot of overlap in their function names. Probably want to be careful about which one is loaded first. Eg, lubridate::week vs data.table::week

Answer (score 0):

If you have some table `dt` with a `day` column and other arbitrary columns, you can add the `i`, `weekday`, `weeknumber` and `WeekRange` in a single call in `data.table`:

```
dt[, ':='(
  i = .I,
  weekday = weekdays(day),
  WeekRange = paste(min(day), max(day), sep = ' - ')
), .(weeknumber = week(day))]
```

The way this works is to group the days by weeknumber, or week(day), and then to paste the min date and max date in those groups together to create a date range for every week.

Here's a mock table to experiment with:

```
n <- 100
dt <-
  data.table(
    day = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-01-01'), by = 'day', length.out = n),
    a = runif(n),
    b = runif(n)
  )
```