# How to use mutate to create a variable that will give me a the dates for a week in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

this is my data. my dates are in year-month-day format

```
Date
2020-01-02 
2020-01-05
2020-01-07
2020-01-08
2020-01-10
2020-01-15
2020-01-16
```

I want to create a new column that will tell me what range of dates of that falls on that follows the calendar system.

```
Date             Range
2020-01-02       01/01-01/03
2020-01-05       01/05-01/11
2020-01-07       01/05-01/11
2020-01-08       01/05-01/11
2020-01-10       01/05-01/11
2020-01-15       01/12-01/18
2020-01-16       01/12-01/18
```

How can i do this?

Comment: `lubridate::week` could help depending on the ranges you are looking at.

Comment: @caldwellst That works to tell me what week of the year the record falls on, but I need the output to be the actual range.

Comment: Again, not sure what range you're looking for, but have a look at other questions regarding [ranges and lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758279/week-range-output-in-r), should find your answer there.

Comment: What if it were to be work weeks?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `floor_date` and `ceiling_date` from `lubridate`. In this example, an `interval` is created with a date range, from Sunday to Saturday.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Range = interval(
    floor_date(Date, "week"),
    ceiling_date(Date, "week") - 1
  ))
```

**Output**

```
        Date                          Range
1 2020-01-02 2019-12-29 UTC--2020-01-04 UTC
2 2020-01-05 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC
3 2020-01-07 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC
4 2020-01-08 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC
5 2020-01-10 2020-01-05 UTC--2020-01-11 UTC
6 2020-01-15 2020-01-12 UTC--2020-01-18 UTC
7 2020-01-16 2020-01-12 UTC--2020-01-18 UTC
```